AOSP 6.0 , init process , try print call stack
Now I am learing aosp 6.0 code .
When i read init process code , which on the path of system/core/init/ , I want to print function call stack .
I try write the code on init.cpp
#include <utils/CallStack.h>

  android::CallStack stack;
  stack.update();
  stack.log("TomYeo : CallStackDemo");

I got link error .
system/core/libutils/CallStack.cpp:43: error: undefined reference to 'Backtrace::Create(int, int, BacktraceMap*)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

On my understand

CallStack are defined on system/core/libutils
Backtrace::Create are defined on system/core/libbacktrace
the system/core/init/Android.mk has dpendent the STATIC LIB :  libutils
The system/core/libutils/Android.mk has dpendent the SHARED LIB : libbacktrace

So on my understand shoudn't linke failed .

On the other way  , i try check Backtrace::Create flag on libbacktrace.so file , fond it .
$ objdump -T libbacktrace.so | grep "Create"
000050c9 g    DF .text  00000056  Base        _ZN12BacktraceMap6CreateEib
00003341 g    DF .text  00000068  Base        _ZN9Backtrace6CreateEiiP12BacktraceMap



I have watch : AOSP print method call stack trace
I have watch : https://yongbingchen.github.io/blog/2013/05/09/dump-stack-in-android-native-c-code/

On my understand , my failed point is build file  . and i don't how to fix it .
on system/core/init/Android.mk I have try many time , the try list is


 LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libbase libbacktrace libutils 



 LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES :=  libbacktrace libutils



always got the same link failed
system/core/libutils/CallStack.cpp:43: error: undefined reference to 'Backtrace::Create(int, int, BacktraceMap*)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


then i try manual run build command  , i found :

it will build success , when my manual execute the command with the libbacktrace.so  full path
but i don't know how to add the libbacktrace.so file full path by mk file
On the way , first build all , throw linker failed

manual execute init build comman ; the command string on the bottom
rebuild with last build result , build success
but flash the result to device  , can't rellay start Android OS . the deivice unlimit relunch .



prebuilts/misc/linux-x86/ccache/ccache prebuilts/clang/linux-x86/host/3.6/bin/clang++
 -nostdlib
 -Bstatic
 -static
 -Wl,--gc-sections
 -o 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/EXECUTABLES/init_intermediates/LINKED/init 
 
 # it will build success , when my manual execute the command with the libbacktrace.so  full path
 # but i don't know how to add the libbacktrace.so file full path by mk file
 /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/lib/libbacktrace.so 

 -L
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/lib 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/lib/crtbegin_static.o   
 -Wl,-z,noexecstack
 -Wl,-z,relro
 -Wl,-z,now
 -Wl,--build-id=md5
 -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel
 -Wl,--fatal-warnings
 -Wl,--icf=safe
 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu
 -Wl,--no-fix-cortex-a8   
 -target arm-linux-androideabi
 -Bprebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/arm-linux-androideabi/bin  
 -Wl,--exclude-libs,libunwind_llvm.a
 -Wl,--no-undefined      
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/EXECUTABLES/init_intermediates/bootchart.o 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/EXECUTABLES/init_intermediates/builtins.o 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/EXECUTABLES/init_intermediates/devices.o 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/EXECUTABLES/init_intermediates/init.o 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/EXECUTABLES/init_intermediates/keychords.o 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/EXECUTABLES/init_intermediates/property_service.o 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/EXECUTABLES/init_intermediates/signal_handler.o 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/EXECUTABLES/init_intermediates/ueventd.o 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/EXECUTABLES/init_intermediates/ueventd_parser.o 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/EXECUTABLES/init_intermediates/watchdogd.o                
 -Wl,--whole-archive  
 -Wl,--no-whole-archive  
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libutils_intermediates/libutils.a 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libinit_intermediates/libinit.a 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libfs_mgr_intermediates/libfs_mgr.a 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libsquashfs_utils_intermediates/libsquashfs_utils.a 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/liblogwrap_intermediates/liblogwrap.a 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libcutils_intermediates/libcutils.a 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libbase_intermediates/libbase.a 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libext4_utils_static_intermediates/libext4_utils_static.a 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libutils_intermediates/libutils.a 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/liblog_intermediates/liblog.a 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libselinux_intermediates/libselinux.a 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libmincrypt_intermediates/libmincrypt.a 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc++_static_intermediates/libc++_static.a 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libdl_intermediates/libdl.a 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libsparse_static_intermediates/libsparse_static.a 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libz_intermediates/libz.a 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libunwind_llvm_intermediates/libunwind_llvm.a 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libdl_intermediates/libdl.a 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libcompiler_rt-extras_intermediates/libcompiler_rt-extras.a
 -Wl,--start-group  
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libc_intermediates/libc.a     prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x-google/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/lib/libatomic.a   prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x-google/libgcc.a
 -Wl,--end-group 
      /Volumes/Beyourself/AOSP/android-6.0.0_r1.tmp/aosp_hammerhead-eng/build_out/target/product/hammerhead/obj/lib/crtend_android.o



Could anyone try help me ?
